# Add an intro screen with YouTube Capture?

Tags: youtube

I have been watching a variety of videos on YouTube, the majority of which are being made with YouTube Capture (at least I'm pretty sure that's the case). I have played around with the app on a iPhone 5S and I cannot figure out how to add title (bumper) screens to the beginning of the videos. Some of the videos I've been watching have an intro picture, with music, and then have text overlayed on the picture. Is this not a feature related to Capture? Or are they doing this in a different way? I've been watching content from 4 different creators and they all have the same font/color etc so I know it has to be a standardized tool they are using. Is this not possible with Capture?

Comment: Are you sure it is YouTube Capture? My kids vlog daily and they have intro graphics, music and text etc. But they use free 3rd party tools on their phones - options seem very standard.